# Isomorphism between finitely generated projective modules over algebra of functions

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module, finitely-generated

Here is the context: Consider two finitely generated projective modules $M$ and $N$ over the commutative algebra of (smooth or) continous functions on a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (they are sections of vector bundles over $\mathcal{M}$). I known that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic. I have a morphism $f : M \to N$ which is one-to-one.

Here is my question: Does this implies that $f$ is onto (so an isomorphism)?

It is easy to construct counter-examples for modules over rings (for instance $M = N = \mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ with $f(n) = 2n$) that is one-to-one but not onto… But what about my specific context?

Thanks in advance

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and suppose $a\in A$, with $a$ neither invertible nor a zero divisor (in your case a function that only vanishes at a single point).

Then the map $f\colon A\to A$, $f(x)=ax$ is one-to-one, but not surjective.

Comment: Well done! This example shows that I can't expect surjectivity without studying the morphism itself in details… That is what I was afraid of.